# DragShadowBuilder Not working in Android 11

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, draggable, drag

Running this simple code on two android emulators:
Pixel 4 API 30,
Pixel 4 API 28

When I long-click the image-view on API 30 emulator the view gets invisible as per the expectations but the views shadow is not visible until I start dragging or moving after long-click whereas it's working fine on API 28 emulator. I tried adding `startDragAndDrop` as `startDrag` was deprecated(showed Gradle warning due to that) But still the issue remains.

If there is a need I can share the video of the issue.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.myimage4);
        imageView.setOnLongClickListener(new MyLongClickListener());
    }

    private final class MyLongClickListener implements View.OnLongClickListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            // Start the drag of the shadow
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                view.startDragAndDrop(null, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            } else {
                view.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            }

            // Hide the actual view as shadow is being dragged
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found a work-around (tested on Pixel 2 API 30 emulator, but not any other).  The idea is to postpone hiding the view being dragged until the dragging starts.  So, I hide the view in my View.OnDragListener.  Here is some of the code from that class:

```
private int mStartedAtX = -99;
private int mStartedAtY = -99;
private boolean mMoved = false;

private void onDragPageItem(DragEvent dragEvent)  {
    int dragAction = dragEvent.getAction();

    // On drag started...
    if (dragAction == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED) {
        mStartedAtX = (int)dragEvent.getX();
        mStartedAtY = (int)dragEvent.getY();
    }

    // On drag exit...
    else if (dragAction == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED) {
        mPageAdmin.handleItemDragExit();
    }

    // On drag motion...
    else if (dragAction == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION) {
        int draggedToX = (int)dragEvent.getX();
        int draggedToY = (int)dragEvent.getY();
        mPageAdmin.handleItemDragMove(draggedToX, draggedToY);

        if (!mMoved) {
            handleFirstMove(draggedToX, draggedToY);
        }
    }

    // On drag drop...
    else if (dragAction == DragEvent.ACTION_DROP) {
        setDragInProgress(false);
        mPageAdmin.handleItemDragDrop();
        resetMovedFields();
    }

    // On drag end...
    else if (dragAction == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED) {
        setDragInProgress(false);
        mPageAdmin.handleItemDragEnd();
        resetMovedFields();
    }
}

private void handleFirstMove(int locX, int locY) {
    if ((locX != mStartedAtX) || (locY != mStartedAtY)) {
        View draggingView =  mPageAdmin.getItemTouchListener().getTouchedView();
        if (draggingView != null) {
            draggingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        mMoved = true;
    }
}

private void resetMovedFields() {
    mStartedAtX = -99;
    mStartedAtY = -99;
    mMoved = false;
}
```

The handleFirstMove() method is where the view is hidden.